# shell script - verfy sha256 sum

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm writing an script for automated downloading files. The author provides checksums.So I'd like to veryfy these automated in the script:

```
if ! [[ $(sha256sum  -c latest-12.tar.bz2.sha256 < latest-12.tar.bz2) = 'latest-12.tar.bz2: OK']]; then
    echo "Fehler im Download"
    exit 1
fi
```

The output:

```
syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `;' 
syntax error near `;' 
`if ! [[ $(sha256sum  -c latest-12.tar.bz2.sha256 < latest-12.tar.bz2) = 'latest-12.tar.bz2: OK']]; then'
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: missing space before `]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, there is a missing space before the closing `]]`.

A better way to achieve your goal is to use:

```
if ! sha256sum --quiet -c latest-12.tar.bz2.sha256; then 
  echo "Fehler im Download"
  exit 1
fi
```

or simply

```
sha256sum --quiet -c latest-12.tar.bz2.sha256 || { echo "Fehler im Download"; exit 1; }
```

Both commands assume the file path indicated in the `latest-12.tar.bz2.sha256` is matching the place where you run the command.